# Insert values from an array into different span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as below:

```
[{
    "category_type": 1,
    "category": 2,
    "name": "gut",
    "description": "bg",
    "registered_location": "1234 1234",
    "current_location": null,
    "contact_person": 4046,
    "barcode": "25757767",
    "nfc_tag_id": "44444543",
    "unit_of_measure": "crate",
    "date_added": "2014-11-13",
    "status": 1
}]
```

I am able to loop through it and get all the values like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, object){
    $.each(object, function(key, value){
        console.log(value);
    })
})
```

I have a certain number of spans that I'd like to get their texts from the different values.The spans are like:

```
<p>Category Type: <span></span></p>
<p>Category: <span></span></p>
<p>Name: <span></span></p>
<p>Description: <span></span></p>
<p>Registered Location: <span></span></p>
<p>Current Location: <span></span></p>
<p>Contact Person: <span></span></p>
<p>Barcode: <span></span></p>
<p>NFC Tag ID: <span></span></p>
<p>Unit of measure: <span></span></p>
<p>Date Added: <span></span></p>
<p>Status: <span></span></p>
```

I want all the empty spans above to get their texts from the JSON values I get above. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with the values. Could you add some example output you're looking for?

Comment: `var span = $('<span />').html(value); $( "body" ).append( span );`

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: @Denny just posted an answer

Comment: @Denny The data your are showing is not real JSON. JSON would be alphabetical ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `p` tags in some `div` and then use `.eq()` like

```
 var counter = 0;
 $.each(object, function(key, value){
    $('.container p').eq(counter).children('span').html(value);
    counter++;
 })
```

**UPD** As GuyT noticed, the order can change, so you can try smth like

```
 $.each(object, function(key, value){
    var str = key.split("_").map(function(elm){
       return elm.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + elm.slice(1);
    }).join(" ");
    $('.container p:contains("'+str+'")').children('span').html(value);
 })
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtb6pza7/1/) displays how to select needed `p` tags.

Comment: Same question: what if the order changes?

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko And if it is multilanguage?

Comment: @GuyT So what's the problem?

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko You are searching on e.g.: 'Category Type'. In Dutch this will be 'Categorie' so your logic isn't right anymore(because the record/model will not change).

Comment: @GuyT So you need either couple of jsons or some sort of dictionary.

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko That's not how it works. Your model will never change with the language!

Comment: @GuyT Ok, it won't. So what's your approach to make it work multilang.

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko I would set an id on a span.

Comment: @GuyT But if you can't? Let's say, you can't change the view itself.

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko Then I would refuse to make it, because you can't rely on the result.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve what you want is to tag each paragraph with a class or id, e.g.

```
<p id="category_type">Category Type: <span></span></p>
<p id="category">Category: <span></span></p>
<p id="name">Name: <span></span></p>
...
```

Then, let's say `data` is your original array, and `obj = data[0]` contains the key/value pairs you want to use. You can then do something like

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    // $('#category_type') selects the element with id "category_type", etc.
    $('#' + key).find('span').text(value);
});
```

Now, this requires you to be able to control the original HTML (e.g. if you are generating it from a template on the server). If you do not have control over the HTML, you will have to do something a bit more hacky, where you parse the contents of the paragraph to determine which data value corresponds to it. For example,

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text(); // `this` is the paragraph element
    var key = txt.trim().toLowerCase().replace(':', '').replace(' ', '_');
    // if `txt` is "Category Type: ", then `key` should be "category_type", etc.
    $(this).find('span').text(obj[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing [Handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) and JavaScript templating!

First we create a template

```
var products = {'products': [yourDataArray] };
var template = "{{#each products}}" + //each iteration will loop over a product
               "<span>{{category_type}}</span>" + //just keep on adding spans to this template.
               "{{/each}}";

var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
var htmlFromTemplate = compiledTemplate(yourData);
```

Now just append the `htmlFromTemplate` to your container.

```
$('.myContainer').append(htmlFromTemplate);
```

This is completely untested, but should work, or at least provide a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have an array of `JSON` objects.  And your trying to loop through the array and access the objects values using their attributes.  If so this would be the implementation:

```
// ARRAY OF JSON OBJECTS
var data = [{"Name":"foo"},{"Name":"bar"}];    

// YOUR LOOP
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('#target').append("<p>Name:<span>" + value.Name + "</span></p>");
    // AND SO ON...
});
```

This will Result in something like this:

```
<p>Name:<span>foo</span></p>
<p>Name:<span>bar</span></p>
```

This should do it.  I hope this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Loop throught all the `p`, and do the following on it: get the text of it, replace `<span></span>` and trim it, so just get the text from it like: `Category Type:`.

With this, replace the `:` character, convert it to lowercase, and replace the spaces to `_` character.

Then you will have the key, like: `category_type`, and then you can use that on your `JSON`.

Get the array value, and put it in the `$(this).find('span');`

Comment: What if the application is multilanguage?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = array[0], index = 0;

// Also you can use jQuery each function
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var value = obj[key];
        $('p').eq(index++).find('span').text(value);
    }
}
```

```js
var array = [{
    "category_type": 1,
    "category": 2,
    "name": "gut",
    "description": "bg",
    "registered_location": "1234 1234",
    "current_location": null,
    "contact_person": 4046,
    "barcode": "25757767",
    "nfc_tag_id": "44444543",
    "unit_of_measure": "crate",
    "date_added": "2014-11-13",
    "status": 1
}], obj = array[0], index = 0;

// Also you can use jQuery each function
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var value = obj[key];
        $('p').eq(index++).find('span').text(value);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Category Type: <span></span></p>
<p>Category: <span></span></p>
<p>Name: <span></span></p>
<p>Description: <span></span></p>
<p>Registered Location: <span></span></p>
<p>Current Location: <span></span></p>
<p>Contact Person: <span></span></p>
<p>Barcode: <span></span></p>
<p>NFC Tag ID: <span></span></p>
<p>Unit of measure: <span></span></p>
<p>Date Added: <span></span></p>
<p>Status: <span></span></p>
```

Comment: And what if the object comes back in an other order?

Comment: That is what i just wanted to ask! agreed with GuyT.

Comment: @Jai This is also what I'm asking myself! I've no idea `:)`

Comment: @Jai use a `@` so people get notified :). ABCFORCE, I've created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3kx5bvg5/2/ (I've changed the first 2 properties, see the result ;))

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to use `$.each`. First you loop through the object and save the values in a temporary array. Afterwards you do an `$.each` on every `<span>`.

```
var obj = {
    "category_type": 1,
    "category": 2,
    "name": "gut",
    "description": "bg",
    "registered_location": "1234 1234",
    "current_location": null,
    "contact_person": 4046,
    "barcode": "25757767",
    "nfc_tag_id": "44444543",
    "unit_of_measure": "crate",
    "date_added": "2014-11-13",
    "status": 1 
};

var temp = []; 

$.each(obj, function(key, value){
    temp.push(value); 
});

$.each($('span'), function( index ){
    $( this ).html(temp[index]); 
});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kx5bvg5/).

---

A better solution would be to use `ids`. Give your `Category Type` span an id of `category_type` and map the values. Look up for the `id` and take it's value.

**HTML**
`<p>Category Type: <span id="category_type"></span></p>` and so on

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value){
    $( '#' + key).html(value);
});
```

This approach is much better because if the values would come back in an other order they still will be placed in the right span.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kx5bvg5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can go throuch all span elements like this:

```
$('span').each(function() {
    //some code to insert data into span
});
```

Or you might add ids to each span which are same as index name and add values to it.

```
var index, value;
for(index in data) {
    value = data[index];
    $('#' + index).html(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var txt = '';
$.each(data, function (key, object) {
    $.each(object, function (key, value) {
        if (key.indexOf('_') !== -1) {
            var c1 = key.split('_')[0].toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.split('_')[0].toString().slice(1);
            var d1 = key.split('_')[1].toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.split('_')[1].toString().slice(1);
            txt = c1 + ' ' + d1;
            console.log(txt);
            $('p:contains(' + txt + ':)').find('span').text(value);
        } else {
            txt = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
            $('p:contains(' + txt + ':)').find('span').text(value);
        }
    });
});
```

checkout the demo below:

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/542zyb9o/1/)

Comment: Category Type is wrong hehe and what if the application is multi-language? ;)

Comment: Then there will be more intelligent way of doing that, although about your comment _hehe_ its done you can see in the updated fiddle though.